# RestAPI data scraping using Python causing 403 FORBIDDEN

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to scrape a REST API for practice using Python, but I kept on getting the HTTP Error 403

Here is my code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
import datetime
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20180124/BTC/USD'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\mubee\Downloads\Annaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\mubee\Downloads\Annaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Users\mubee\Downloads\Annaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Users\mubee\Downloads\Annaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Users\mubee\Downloads\Annaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\mubee\Downloads\Annaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Depending on how well the API is made, 403 could be shown in error. Does the API require any authentication? If so, the API should return 401, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @melwil it does not require any authentication

Answer (score 0):

Try with User-Agent before request,

```
import urllib2

my_url = 'https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20180124/BTC/USD'
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(my_url)
page_html = response.read()
response.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```